# Obj-c is NSMutablearray thread safe in this Queue, and does reading it needs to be queued also?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm working on my IOS app in Xcode 7, and I have had some problems with the thread safety of a Global NSMutableArray which is read many times to do some updates on a tableview.

Because of some strange chrashes, I tried adding this queue to the updating of the global array (global to the view), where the array is updated from a database function that I call (written as a class method with some other global functions). But the update is called from some main threads but also from other calls coming from background threads and timer events.

I add the globals:

```
NSMutableArray *myMutArray ;
dispatch_queue_t the_Queue ;
```

Then in viewdidappear

```
the_Queue = dispatch_queue_create("my_Queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL) ;
```

And my function for updating the array (from another classinstance)

```
-(void)update_array {
     dispatch_sync("my_Queue"),^{
         myMutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithArray:[Globalfunction updatearrayfromdb] ] ;
     }
}
```

With this I was hoping to avoid thread problems, but is it necessary to have a read function also like:

```
-(NSArray*)read_array{
   __block NSArray *array ;
   dispatch_sync("my_Queue",^{
         array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:myMutArray ] ;
    });
    return array;
}
```

Or is this not necessary if the reading of this array are performed on the main thread all the time?
Also, will the dispatch_sync be a block that is run on the main thread, or should I instead call an extra function to make them run on main thread, as it is all methods that don't need to be run in background, but still can get called from several locations.
I was thinking if using NSOperationQueue would be better for this:

```
-(void)update_array {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        myMutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithArray:[Globalfunction updatearrayfromdb] ] ;
 });
)
```

Or would this give a different result? My main goal is basically that all blocks are run on the main thread, but in the order they are called.

And one thing I'm always confused about with this, will these blocks (my dispatch methods and the NSOperation method) get called after an entire method/block has finished on the main thread (f.ex after a -(void) with 20 lines of code has run completely to a finish) or will they get started inside a method/block, but already just after a some line of code has just executed, with more code lines waiting.
(Since this is the thing we are trying to avoid with thread safety, it would be good to know when exactly my threads will execute?

Also is there a way to avoid that the same block gets called several times in a row if its added many times, like when its stacked like this:

```
call read
call update <- if this is the one progress now
call read
call read <- these returns the same so are unnecessary and would waste time
call read <- these returns the same so are unnecessary and would waste time
call read <- these returns the same so are unnecessary and would waste time
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray` is not thread safe;  not for simultaneous writing and *not for simultaneous reading, either*.

If you have a mutable array that spans threads, you need to serialize reads and writes.  The easiest way to do that is with a serial queue that you dispatch_sync() all operations to (like in the code you provided).

There is no need to do all operations on the main queue (and, in fact, doing so could lead to responsiveness issues).

Alternatively, if writing is fairly infrequent *or* it is OK for the data displayed to the user (or otherwise) to lag slightly, then consider calling `copy` on the `NSMutableArray` to create an `NSArray` instance as that will be thread safe.

---

The main queue is serial.  Only one block at a time can be processed on it and the entire block must execute and return before another block will be executed.

Comment: Reading [Mike Ash](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-14-whats-new-in-gcd.html) one might conclude that `NSMutableArray` is multiple-readers/single-writer safe as he states `NSMutableDictionary` is. I think such claims are made elsewhere as well. Your answer seems to state, with emphasis, that it is single reader/single writer only. Normally trustworthy sources disagreeing. Can you confirm that these types are not multiple reader safe and barrier solutions, e.g. as shown by Mike Ash, are not valid?

Comment: @CRD The documentation very explicitly states that *mutable collection classes are not thread safe*.   There are no concessions made for "read only" roles.  Now, the implementation *might* be thread safe in a read only role, but the documentation makes no such claim and, therefore, any conclusion that it is true is, at best, an assumption (example:  a collection class *could* re-balance contents based on read operation style/frequencey).

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping you might produce a different reference, or maybe inside knowledge... That document also says "Check the class documentation for additional details" - and we know how worthwhile that is so how should one treat other "explicit" statements in the same document? Apple documentation isn't always, shall we say "precise", as one might wish. Enough said! ;-)

Comment: @CRD The NSMutableDictionary documentation has no verbiage about threading, which precisely means that the over-arching API documentation applies.  The docs generally take the approach of only calling out behavior specific to a class or behavior that is in conflict with the overall standard.

Comment: We're going off topic, but that is partly my point about the documentation. Want to know the thread safety of `NSMutableDictionary`? One might go to its documentation, you won't find anything. The answer lies in an *appendix* to another document, the path to which may not be obvious. One might hope that on such a critical issue the definitive statement wasn't buried in an appendix. It appears Mike Ash might have missed it, and he can hardly be described as a novice! Anyway, thanks for responding, have a nice day.

Comment: @CRD The "Threading Programming Guide" is not an appendix to the documentation.  It is an over-arching document that describes the standard behavior of the entire framework (most of the SDK, actually).  While I can understand your criticism, the counter criticism is that if every single bit of critical information were repeated in every class reference, they would be HUGE;   threading, coding, KVC, retain/release/autorelease behavior, and all the rest of the standard kit wide behaviors?  Which ones are in or out?

Comment: I maybe wasn't clear, the lists of which classes are (not) thread-safe is in an appendix in that Guide (it's Appendix A), the Guide itself isn't an appendix! As to where the boundary should be, maybe not quite where it is now given that people miss this - I might have found it, which we'll put down to luck, but some of the giants on whose shoulders we stand clearly haven't. I know it can be a difficult decision, wearing one of my hats I've had to make such decisions. Again thanks for responding, have a nice day.